# How to uninstall completely "Blackberry Device Manager"?

Tags: macos, login-items

I've uninstalled the blackberry software from my mac using the original uninstaller utility. This software did not work properly, so it left a login item called called "Blackberry Device Manager" appearing on the "Users & Groups" tab at "System Preferences" with a yellow triangle signaling an error.

How can I delete this faulted login item?

[image: Screenshot for my "Users & Groups" preference panel]

**Update**
[Here is a deeper Blackberry component cleansing procedure](https://superuser.com/questions/647762/how-can-i-remove-blackberry-tools-entirely-from-os-x)

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the problem to help us help you better.

Comment: @cksum done! this is the screenshoot

Comment: Unlock the System Preferences and give it another try (by clicking that lock icon in the bottom left of the window).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I updated my macbook to Mountain Lion. Then I disabled any kind of privilege for all existing accounts and finally I deleted the entry with the minus button...

Answer (score 5):

You may want to try getting rid of the related files in `/Library/LaunchDaemons` and `/Library/LaunchAgents`.

Those will all start with `com.rim.*`, so you can run:

```
sudo rm /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.rim.*
sudo rm /Library/LaunchAgents/com.rim.*
```

Answer (score 2):

Click the lock to make changes. That'll unlock the login item, which is for All Users. Then you can select it and click the minus button.

Answer (score 0):

You've successfuly deleted the *Blackberry Device Manager*. The yellow sign informs you that the *System* cant find that item any more, as it no longer exists.

Just select it and click the minus sing above to get rid of it.

**EDIT:**  Apparently [someone](https://discussions.apple.com/message/17018374#17018374) with the same issue found a workaround. Creating a new user an pointing it to the same home directory allowed him to delete the login item.

To do so just go create a **New User**, and **Right Clicking** on it, select *Advance Options*. A new window will prompt, were you'll be able to change your *Home Directory*. [Here](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57365307-263/moving-your-home-folder-in-os-x/) you can find some more detailed information.

I'll try to find a not so tricky way, though.

Comment: The minus sign appears disabled.

Comment: Having the item selected? Not the check box, but selected in the list.

Comment: The entire item appears disabled and it is so for the minus sign. Also, the checkbox is checked and cannot be edited.

Comment: @Juan Pablo Contreras, try pressing the `Delete` key while it's highlighted.

Comment: @ioi doesn't work...

Comment: I'll edit my answer, adding new info i've just found.

Answer (score 0):

Try Looking in the folder:

```
System/Library/Extensions
```

Search for anything that has the "Blackberry" or "RIM" name in the extension (with .kext at the end of the file) and move it out of the folder. If you are asked for your password you will need to enter it to authorize the change.

Also look for these in your ~/ folder:

```
/Library/Application Support/BlackBerry/BBDaemon

/Library/Application Support/BlackBerry/BBLaunchAgent.app

/Library/Application Support/BlackBerry/BlackBerry Device Manager.app
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a grayed out login item for another application, but it was removed after I deleted `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist` and restarted the Mac.

The preferences for login items are normally stored in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist` and `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist` does not normally exist.

While you are in there you also have to get 'loginwindow.plist' which includes yet another call for '/Library/Application Support/BlackBerry/BlackBerry Device Manager.app'. It took me over an hour to find this final version (finally via 'fgrep -iR "Blackberry" /Library').